# Combining parallax scrolling with scrollify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-scrollify

I learned using parallax scrolling from http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/
I tried using Scrollify jQuery plugin for snapping to sections. Both of them working great for me. But when I try combine these two effects, it is not working. I want to have the parallax effect when i scroll through couple of transparent background sections. Can someone please help me achieve this? Thanks in advance...

```
<div class="parallax">
<div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer--back">
</div>
<div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer--base">
    <section class="section"></section>
    <section class="section"></section>
    <section class="section"></section>
</div>
```

In the above code, I want to include the scrollify effect inside parallax_layer--base div, so that the background scrolls slower and foreground pages snaps to sections while scrolling. (the parallax* class attributes are defined in the link mentioned above.)

```js
$(function(){
   $(".scroller").css({"height":$(window).height()});
   $.scrollify({
     section:".scroller",
  scrollbars:false,
   });
 });
```

```css
 .parallax {
 perspective-origin-x: 100%;
 perspective: 1px;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax_layer {
  transform-origin-x: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}
.parallax_layer--base {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  height: 500vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: white;
}
.parallax_layer--back {
  background-image: url("path/to/image.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(11);
}
section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one { background: yellow; }
.two { background: red; }
.three { background: green; }
.four { background: black; }
.five{ background: blue; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollify/1.0.4/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer--back">
 </div>
    <div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer--base">
      <section class="scroller one"></section>
      <section class="scroller two"></section>
      <section class="scroller three"></section>
      <section class="scroller four"></section>
      <section class="scroller five"></section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're trying and particulary what is working/isn't

Comment: I have included the code for ur review...